# Attachment field cannot be updated

Tags: list-view, list-form, sharepoint-list

Kindly assist,when attaching a document in sharepoint 2016 list i get an error message: **Attachment field cannot be updated**...but am able to attach in other different lists in our sharepoint 2016. It is this particular list that gives an error.
Thank you.[image]

Comment: Did you check whether in the advanced settings of this list the Attachments are disabled?

Comment: Attachments are enabled in the advanced settings.., it has been working well all along. now it's failing with this error.

Comment: I see. Then my next assumption that perhaps a custom field named Attachments has been added to the list is also not useful, isnt't it?. All I have seen about this issue is that many people run into such cases without solution. Most of them have just rebuilt the library :-/

Comment: Have you investigated ULS logs form more information about the error?

Comment: I reversed the Rating Settings-(not to be rate) for the List and now am able to attach.  Thank you